# Unable to extract CSS selector and attribute value in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

I am unable to extract the CSS selector and attribute from the response body of the http request.
I need to extract state value from the below response body. Kindly help!!

Comment: What have you tried? What is the error/result you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to provide:

- at least partial response
- indicate what you want to extract
- your current configuration of the CSS Selector Extractor

Without it you will be able to get only "generic" response like one below:

Given this simple piece of HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="I want this value"/>
```

You can use the following setup:

- CSS Selector: `input[name=state]`
- Attribute: `value`

[image]

Demo:

More information:

- [CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
- [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter)